# Azure DevOps MultiRepo Pipeline: checkout the repo that triggered the pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I use multiple Repos in my pipeline as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#multi-repo-checkout).

My code looks like the following (excerpt):

resources:

```
  repositories:
  - repository: r1
    type: git
    name: XXX/r1
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - f/*
  - repository: r2
    type: git
    name: XXX/r2
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - f/*
```

Now I would only checkout EITHER r1 OR r2: only the repo that triggered the pipeline.

I know I can do

```
  - checkout: r1
```

and

```
  - checkout: r2
```

but I want only to checkout r1 when the pipeline was triggered by a change on r1 or r2 when the pipleine was triggered by r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally checkout repository using predefined variable Build.Repository.Name

This example more or less should work

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'repositoryOne') }}:
  - checkout: r1
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'repositoryTwo') }}:
  - checkout: r2
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services